# How to link an event in tab in ipywidgets?

Tags: python, jupyter, ipywidgets

In below code I created 2 tabs with a text box and a button in inside each tab. I want to select button `one` and link an event for it. How can I do it?

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

lst = ['one', 'two']
list_widgets  = [
    widgets.HBox([widgets.Text(
        placeholder="name",
        description=name,
        disabled=False),
                  widgets.Button(
                  description="ok")]) for name in lst]

children=list_widgets
tab = widgets.Tab(children)
[tab.set_title(num, name) for num, name in enumerate(lst)]

display(tab)
```

Answer (score 2):

To link an action to an [ipywidget button](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#Button) you use the [`on_click`](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Events.html#Special-events) method for a button you have created.  From ipywidget:

> The Button is not used to represent a data type. Instead the button
>   widget is used to handle mouse clicks. The on_click method of the
>   Button can be used to register function to be called when the button
>   is clicked.

But, if you create your layout using your strategy you'll be somewhat limited with your buttons because they'll have the same action (the same button will be referenced).  In this example `button` is used on both tabs:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

def click(h):
    print('button click')

button = widgets.Button(description="ok")
button.on_click(click)

lst = ['one', 'two']
list_widgets  = [
    widgets.HBox([widgets.Text(
        placeholder="name",
        description=name,
        disabled=False),
    button]) for name in lst]

children=list_widgets

tab = widgets.Tab(children)
[tab.set_title(num, name) for num, name in enumerate(lst)]

display(tab)
```

With some modifications you can add two buttons with different actions:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

def click1(h):
    print('button one click')

def click2(h):
    print('button two click')

one = widgets.Button(description="ok")
one.on_click(click1)

two = widgets.Button(description="ok")
two.on_click(click2)

btn = [one, two]
lst = ["one", "two"]
list_widgets  = [
    widgets.HBox([widgets.Text(
        placeholder="name",
        description=name,
        disabled=False),
    btn[num]]) for num, name in enumerate(lst)]

children=list_widgets

tab = widgets.Tab(children)
[tab.set_title(num,name) for num, name in enumerate(lst)]

display(tab)
```